# openpyxl table ref using matrix dimensions

Tags: python, openpyxl

if I have a matrix (2d list) that I am writing to an excel doc, how can I state the table ref using a1 cell notation using the dimensions of the array?

for example:

```py
headers = ['first', 'second', 'third']

data = [
 [1,2,3],
 [1,2,3]
]
```

I know that the headers span from A1:C1 and the rows from 1:3 so I can deduce the table ref is A1:C3 but for a much larger matrix; for example a table with range A1:CD75 I am not sure how to properly calculate that range knowing only the dimensions of the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution I came up with uses `openpyxl.worksheet.cell_range.CellRange` like so

```py
ref = CellRange(
            min_col=1, min_row=1, max_col=len(headers), max_row=len(data)
        ).coord

table = Table(
            displayName="Table1",
            ref=ref,
        )
```

Comment: Perfectly reasonable to do this. CellRanges also have utility methods that let you adjust their size. Otherwise you coud use the utility function `get_column_letter()`, which is what CellRange does.